# How to put a Slider widget into the Better Exposed Filters for Ubercart price and other product features?

Tags: 7, ubercart, javascript

How to put a Slider widget into the Better exposed filters and product search result view in Drupal 7 for Ubercart price and other product features?

[image]

I have developed an ecommerce shop, and need to a add slider widget to search products.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Jquery UI and most of its widgets are embedded with D7 core, in *misc/ui* folder. First add these lines to your theme template file (`sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/template.php`) :

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {//replace YOUR_THEME by your theme name
  $view = $vars['view'];
  switch($view->name) {      
    case 'YOUR_VIEW' : //replace YOUR_VIEW by your view name

      drupal_add_library('system','ui.slider');
      drupal_add_css('/misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css');
      break;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to clear cache.

Your filter must be compatible with is between, lower, greater operators. This is fine for  numeric fields. In the filter setup, set it as exposed and choose "is between" operator.

Last, in views advanced settings, in the BEF setup screen, select Jquery ui slider for your filter and adjust other settings like range at convenience.

### EDIT

To answer your comments, **don't edit Bartik or other core files**. 
You can easily **create a subtheme** as following :

1. Create the folder: `/sites/all/themes/vassia`
2. Create the file `/sites/all/themes/vassia/vassia.info`
3. put this code in `vassia.info`

   ```
   name = vassia
   description = my first subtheme
   core = 7.x
   base theme = bartik

   stylesheets[all][] = css/vassia.css
   stylesheets[all][] = css/colors.css

   regions[header] = Header
   regions[help] = Help
   regions[page_top] = Page top
   regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
   regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

   regions[featured] = Featured
   regions[content] = Content
   regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
   regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

   regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
   regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
   regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last

   regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
   regions[footer_secondcolumn] = Footer second column
   regions[footer_thirdcolumn] = Footer third column
   regions[footer_fourthcolumn] = Footer fourth column
   regions[footer] = Footer

   settings[shortcut_module_link] = 0
   ```
4. Create a file named: `/sites/all/themes/vassia/css/vassia.css` for your future css custom
5. If you need colors features, copy the file `/themes/bartik/css/colors.css` to `/sites/all/themes/vassia/css/colors.css` and copy the folder and its contents `/themes/bartik/color/` to `/sites/all/themes/vassia/color/`
6. Go to the the Administration > Appearance page to enable your new subtheme called Vassia

Everything is very well explained in [Creating a subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) DO page. **Now the slider part**

1. Create a file `/sites/all/themes/vassia/template.php`
2. Write exactly this code in your template.php file :

   ```
   <?php 
   /**
    * Implements template_preprocess_views_view().
    */
   function vassia_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
     $view = $vars['view'];
     switch($view->name) {      
       case 'productviewwithsliders' :

         drupal_add_library('system','ui.slider');
         drupal_add_css('/misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css');
         break;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Double check the view name. Clear all caches

Enjoy

Comment: have tried, slider does not appear, what to do to fix?

Comment: Where should I put that code exactly, in what file, and php tags are necessary? Thank you.

Comment: @VassiaAlk I edited the answer. Add it in template.php file as explained. If it's empty, put only opening  `<?php` tags before, not  closing tag after.

Comment: I wrote in Bartik: /**
       * Implements template_preprocess_views_view().
        */
             function bartik_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {//replace     YOUR_THEME by your theme name
  $view = $vars['view'];
  switch($view->name) {      
    case 'ProductViewWithsliders' : //replace YOUR_VIEW by your view name
      //global $theme_path;
      drupal_add_library('system','ui.slider');
      drupal_add_css('/misc/ui/jquery.ui.slider.css');
      break;
  }
} No slider appears...

Comment: You should not edit core theme  files. Don't you have your own theme ? Then please write the code you did put into your question below an edit title, and format it correctly so that I'm able to read it. Last, it seems it's not the system name of your view which you can find in the edit url something like /admin/structure/views/view/your_view_name, with lowercase and underscores instead of spaces. You're not far...

Comment: I use Bartik theme, I tried various names and no slider appears. Did you try similar on your machine? I don`t write themes, started to write modules, learning curve goes forward. Thank you. Is there any other way to put sliders in BEF?

Comment: @VassiaAlk I added more explanations.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Kojo and Forum, I did exactly as you advised, subtheme works, but no slider appears. Can`t find the reason, changed names in all variants. Will try on on the other computer and Drupal instance and on Drupal 8. Are there any other modules for sliders in BEF or other filters?

Comment: Sorry to ear that!  Another point, try  installing JQUERY UPDATE and choose 1.7 or upper version..Tell me if it work please. you may also declare your slider in js behavior but I think it's not necessary anymore with last version.  No errors messages in dblog ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try [Slide Field Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/sliderfield) Module

> The sliderfield module provides a new widget for number fields
>   (decimal, float, and integer) and a form element. When creating a
>   numeric field, select the slider widget.
>
> This project uses the jQuery UI slider included with core.

Or this Module [Select with Style](https://www.drupal.org/project/select_with_style)

> The Select with Style project download contains two modules containing
>   three styleable widgets:
>
> Slide with Style, contains a field widget to enter numbers or list
>   values via sliders when creating content and also to filter using this
>   widget in Views. This includes double-handled sliders to input
>   "in-between" ranges. Select with Style, comprises two widgets to enter
>   taxonomy fields, in particular hierarchical taxonomies, when creating
>   content and also to filter by these taxonomy fields in Views These are
>   light-weight solutions that have no external dependencies. No external
>   libraries are required. Only minimum configuration, no permissions, no
>   coding. Just style!

Comment: Nagarjuna, don't you think it's would be an overkill to add another module for the slider, since VassiaAlk already configured BEF for his project, which comes with Slider feature ? :)

Comment: Nāgārjuna is the name of a Buddhist monk who founded the Mahāyāna Buddhist school... Is it a nickname or your real name ? Sorry for being curious ;)

Comment: I provided an option if you don't wanna code, few people like that few not. And It is my Name :). So nice of you, you just shared that I dont know

Comment: Nice of you, dear patriarch !

Comment: thank you, people, Select with Style and Slide Views widgets do not apprear in BEF. Only JQ UI appears but on a final view there is not. I am trying to add that code you have published.